# Asp Gridview: How Prevent Empty columns from binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created a Asp GridView with 5 columns. But not always does the sql query return 5 columns, certain times it is 4 and 3 as well. So, when lesser number of columns are returned, I get the following error:- 
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ExactRate3'

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure the query always return 5 values, even if you select only 3 columns. You can aslo set the value for those dummy columns.

```
SELECT ExactRate1, ExactRate2, NULL AS ExactRate3, 'emptyString' AS ExactRate4, 0 AS ExactRate5
```

This way the GridView databinding will find `ExactRate3` and not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove static columns from GridView and set property AutoGenerateColumns='true'

Comment: There are a lot of template settings, would that be possible, if the gridview fields are static.

Comment: Are you binding DataTable or List<Type>?